About an Argument for Relative Homology Groups
I am working on showing that $H_0(X,A)=0$ iff $A$ meets every path component of $X$. I know that this question has been answered, I just think an argument that is commonly used for one direction does not follow immediately.
Assuming $H_0(X,A)=0$, we know that $i_*:H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is surjective from the long exact sequence. The argument I am having trouble with is:
Given $x_0\in X$, since $i_*$ is surjective, there exists a generator $a_0$ of $C_0(A)$ such that $i_*([a_0])=[x_0]$. The rest follows.
I don't understand why $a_0$ has to be a generator. Can it not be a linear combination of 0 singular simplices? So we can have $i_*([\sum c_i a_i])=[x_0]$.
I want to understand in cases like this (surjection from one homology group to another) whether I can assume the element that surjection provides is a generator in general.
Thank you in advance, I feel like I am missing something.

For any space $X$, the group $H_0(X)$ is free abelian with rank equal to the number of path connected components of $X$, and each copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by, or a generator may be chosen to be, a point in the corresponding path component. Also, given two points in $X$, the $0$-cycles that they determine are homologous (and so represent the same homology class) if and only if there is a path between those points.
Now suppose that $f: A \to X$ is any continuous map. Then on $H_0$, if $a$ is a point in $A$, then $f_*([a]) = [f(a)]$. Therefore the map $f_*$ will take generators to generators. So if $f_*$ is surjective on $H_0$, then each generator in $H_0(X)$ must be the image of a generator in $H_0(A)$.
If you want to think about this in terms of $C_0$: the group $H_0$ is a quotient of $C_0$, so $H_0$ is generated by generators of $C_0$. That is, every generator of $C_0$ gives a generator of $H_0$, and the generators of $H_0$ may be chosen to be generators of $C_0$. (This holds in degree zero, it doesn't generalize.) There are other possible choices of generators of $H_0$; for example if $x$ and $y$ are in the same path component, then $2[x] - [y]$ will be a generator of $H_0$, and more generally any linear combination of $0$-simplices in the same path component with coefficients adding up to $\pm 1$ will give a generator of $H_0$. But you can always choose to use a single vertex for each generator.

Thank you for your response! On the second paragraph, I understand that every generator of A is mapped to a generator of X. I cannot see why this should imply that every generator of X is mapped by a generator of A even if surjectivity holds.

Because the map sends generators to generators, if $[x]$ is a generator of $H_0(X)$ which is not hit by a generator of $H_0(A)$, then $[x]$ is not in the image at all. Said differently, $H_0(A)$ and $H_0(X)$ are both direct sums of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, and the map sends each $\mathbb{Z}$ summand in $H_0(A)$ isomorphically onto a $\mathbb{Z}$ summand in $H_0(X)$. So each generator of such a summand in $H_0(X)$ is either hit by a generator or is not in the image at all.
